# throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function'); ERROR when i try to run wp-env on local xubuntu

Tags: wordpress, plugins

So basically when i download my plugin from git and run a wp-env i get this error ...

```
dara@dara-HP:~/Desktop/ha/ft-wp-plugin-master$ wp-env start
internal/util.js:209
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at Object.promisify (internal/util.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@wordpress/env/lib/config/detect-directory-type.js:15:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@wordpress/env/lib/config/config.js:12:29)
```

`sudo npm -g i @wordpress/env`

seems to work fine though ...

```
node -v
v8.10.0
```

Comment: I can't find any internal/util.js folder/file on the harddrive. There are lots of util.js files and some wp-util.js files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can ascertain, it was a pemission issue with npm and node. I'm not on that system atm so I can't post my exact cli commands. But basically ...

I used chmod to set node_modules recursively to 777 permissions and then uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm as root.

Seems to fix this issue ... I'm the only user on this system so I'm hoping the root install and chmod won't leave the system vulnerable?